# R: identify column of a table by variable of string, when the column is on the left side of assignment?

Tags: r

I need to have a function to collapse certain column of a contingency table, like the following:

```
collapse.a.column <-function(tb, a.column, collapse.list) {
  return(collapse.table(tb, <something_to_identify_a.column> = collapse.list))
}
```

The `a.column` is a string.

I'm having hard time to express the column corresponding to the string as name  `a.column` on the left side of the assignment `=`

It seems that this a general requirement to express column on left side of assignment, as in transformation of data.frame, etc.

Thanks of for your help!

Comment: what do you mean by collapse, can you provide an example

Comment: Where does the function `collapse.table` come from? An existing package? Or do you need to write it as well?

Comment: collapse.table is from vcdExtra, it combines some factor levels along dimensions of a contingency table. It's not the central issue of my question, my key question is how one can express the column/tag through variable on the left-hand side of assignment in many R function can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a job for `do.call`

Here is the example under `?vcdExtra::collapse.table`

```
library('vcdExtra')

# create some sample data in table form
set.seed(1)
sex <- c("Male", "Female")
age <- letters[1:6]
education <- c("low", 'med', 'high')
data <- expand.grid(sex=sex, age=age, education=education)
counts <- rpois(36, 100) 
data <- cbind(data, counts)
t1 <- xtabs(counts ~ sex + age + education, data=data)

structable(t1)

#                  age   a   b   c   d   e   f
# sex    education                            
# Male   low            93 112  84 107  96  93
#        med            99 109 105 107  80 110
#        high           95  98  99 109 111  98
# Female low           113 104 104 105  92  97
#        med            99 108 109 100 105  93
#        high           97 103  86  95 107  97

# collapse age to 3 levels
t2 <- collapse.table(t1, age=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"))
structable(t2)

#                  age   A   B   C
# sex    education                
# Male   low           205 191 189
#        med           208 212 190
#        high          193 208 209
# Female low           217 209 189
#        med           207 209 198
#        high          200 181 204
```

With `do.call`, you get the same results

```
t3 <- do.call('collapse.table', list(table = t1,
                                     age = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")))
structable(t3)

#                  age   A   B   C
# sex    education                
# Male   low           205 191 189
#        med           208 212 190
#        high          193 208 209
# Female low           217 209 189
#        med           207 209 198
#        high          200 181 204
```

So that your function could look like

```
collapse.a.column <- function(table = t1, ...) {
  do.call('collapse.table', c(list(table = t1, ...)))
}

t4 <- collapse.a.column(age = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"))
structable(t4)

#                  age   A   B   C
# sex    education                
# Male   low           205 191 189
#        med           208 212 190
#        high          193 208 209
# Female low           217 209 189
#        med           207 209 198
#        high          200 181 204
```

Since `collapse.table` has arguments `(table, ...)`, you can think of it as you have a function which will accept anything as a parameter, some you want to give, some you do not. `do.call` is useful in this situation when you want to pass a list of arguments to a function but maybe you will not always have/need a subset of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! So the key is not to name the column name to collapse, only provide the concrete column value when calling collapse.a.column